# 400 Bad Request on Alexa AddOrUpdateReport using JSON from documentation

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My issue is basically described in title but I'll add a little bit more details here.

I'm trying to proactively send an update report to Alexa's Event Hub for Smart Home skills, however this fails with a 400 Bad Request error, and this is what the server responds:

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "System",
        "name": "Exception",
        "messageId": "a154410c-2364-4c5b-9028-accde5048e1e"
    },
    "payload": {
        "code": "INVALID_REQUEST_EXCEPTION",
        "description": "Event or endpoint is missing in the request."
    }
}
```

I decided then to check if my request was wrong by sending the one that can be found on their documentation, and I'm getting the very same error.

This is the JSON copied from Amazon's documentation (I just replaced device metadata and the token):

```
{
  "event": {
    "header": {
      "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
      "name": "AddOrUpdateReport",
      "payloadVersion": "3",
      "messageId": "5f8a426e-01e4-4cc9-8b79-65f8bd0fd8a4"
    },
    "payload": {
      "endpoints": [
        {
          "endpointId": "<unique ID of the endpoint>",
          "manufacturerName": "Sample Manufacturer",
          "description": "Smart Light by Sample Manufacturer",
          "friendlyName": "Kitchen Light",
          "additionalAttributes":  {
            "manufacturer" : "Sample Manufacturer",
            "model" : "Sample Model",
            "serialNumber": "<the serial number of the device>",
            "firmwareVersion" : "<the firmware version of the device>",
            "softwareVersion": "<the software version of the device>",
            "customIdentifier": "<your custom identifier for the device>"
          },
          "displayCategories": [
            "LIGHT"
          ],
          "capabilities": [
            {
              "type": "AlexaInterface",
              "interface": "Alexa.PowerController",
              "version": "3",
              "properties": {
                "supported": [
                  {
                    "name": "powerState"
                  }
                ],
                "proactivelyReported": true,
                "retrievable": true
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "AlexaInterface",
              "interface": "Alexa.BrightnessController",
              "version": "3",
              "properties": {
                "supported": [
                  {
                    "name": "brightness"
                  }
                ],
                "proactivelyReported": true,
                "retrievable": true
              }
            }
          ],
          "connections": [
          ],
          "cookie": {
          }
        }
      ],
      "scope": {
        "type": "BearerToken",
        "token": "access-token-from-Amazon"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is why it reports that `event` or `endpoints` are missing if they're clearly there and if this JSON is the one that they provide in their documentation.

Does anyone have this issue too?

EDIT: pasting my payload as requested.

```
{
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
            "name": "AddOrUpdateReport",
            "payloadVersion": "3",
            "messageId": "132137185729061389"
        },
        "payload": {
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "endpointId": "Rmxvb2RTZW5zb3JfMDE=",
                    "friendlyName": "Flood sensor",
                    "description": "Flood sensor",
                    "manufacturerName": "MyCompany",
                    "displayCategories": [
                        "ACTIVITY_TRIGGER"
                    ],
                    "cookie": {
                        "DeviceType": "FloodSensor"                 
                    },
                    "capabilities": [{
                            "interface": "Alexa",
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "version": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "interface": "Alexa.EndpointHealth",
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "version": "3",
                            "properties": {
                                "supported": [{
                                    "name": "connectivity"
                                }],
                                "proactivelyReported": true,
                                "retrievable": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }                
            ],
            "scope": {
                "type": "BearerToken",
                "token": "<redacted>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you replacing the `endpointId` with correct ID? The same ID you would have used in your initial Discovery response.

Comment: As in the OP: `I just replaced device metadata and the token`, so yes, `endpointId` is taken from a Discovery response.

Comment: Can you share your actual JSON payload (rather than the one from Amazon's docs)?

Comment: Added to the OP.

Comment: Thanks for adding that - I can't see anything obvious there. Do you have a specific error message? One thing that looks a little weird is the first Object in the capabilities Array - the one without any properties... Does that need to be there?

Comment: Adding or removing the first capability changes nothing. The error is the one in the OP: "Event or endpoint is missing in the request".

Comment: Looks like someone on the Amazon forums ([here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/210489/deletereport-giving-400-bad-request-event-or-endpo.html)) had the same issue. Unfortunately a fix isn't posted. Might be a good idea to also ask there. Sorry couldn't help further.